# What do people mean by "DOM Manipulation" and how would I do that?

Tags: html, dom

I always hear people talk about DOM this, manipulate the DOM, change the DOM, traverse the DOM; but what exactly does this mean?

What is the DOM and why would I want to do something with it?

Comment: The below answers are where it's at. However, here is an analogy. With respect website front end development. You can think of the DOM as the building materials you use to put up a building. Frameworks, like jQuery, and design patterns are the customizable blueprints for your building. The IDE and software to build are your tools. The language is your speciality (mason, carpentry).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) is basically an API you use to interface the document with, and is available in many languages as a library ( JS is one of those languages ). The browser converts all the HTML in your web page to a tree based on the nesting. Pop open Firebug and look at the HTML structure. That is the tree I'm talking about.

If you want to change any HTML you can interact with the DOM API in order to do so.

```
<html>
 <head><script src="file.js"></script></head>
 <body>blah</body>
</html>
```

In `file.js` I can reference the body using:

```
onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.display='none';
}
```

The `getElementsByTagName` is a method of the `document` object. I am manipulating the `body` element, which is a DOM element. If I wanted to traverse and find say, a span I can do this:

```
onload = function() {
 var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
 for ( var i = els.length; i--; ) {
    if ( els[i].nodeType == 1 && els[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'span' ) {
       alert( els[i] )
    }
 }
}
```

I am traversing the nodeList given back by getElementsByTagName in the snippet above, and looking for a span based on the `nodeName` property.

Comment: So the DOM is the API that can be used in Javascript to modify HTML?

Comment: Yes, and there are libraries in other languages as well for the DOM.

Comment: Yeah! This answer is definitely what I was looking for. Now I won't feel like a dunce when people are talking about it. Thanks again!

Comment: browser should support(consists the) DOM which includes the document object right?

Comment: What exactly constitutes manipulation? Any changes in a property value related to a DOM element? I mean changing opacity or color alone, are they considered manipulations?

Comment: @Neil: Yes. Affecting a DOM element is called DOM manipulation.

Comment: @meder you said `JS is one of those languages`. So what are the other languages to manipulate the DOM?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi TypeScript can also do this, but the language isn't worth talking about, as it's only available in IE.

Answer (score 20):

It means working with the [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which is an API to work with XML like documents.

From w3 on the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/):

> The Document Object Model is a platform- and language-neutral interface that will allow programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure and style of documents. The document can be further processed and the results of that processing can be incorporated back into the presented page. This is an overview of DOM-related materials here at W3C and around the web.

One of the functions mostly used in DOM work is:

```
getElementById
```

---

Manipulating/Changing the DOM means using this API to change the document (add elements, remove elements, move elements around etc...).

Traversing the DOM means navigating it - selecting specific elements, iterating over groups of elements etc...

Answer (score 2):

**In short:**

When a web page is loaded, the browser creates a **Document Object Model** of the page, which is an **object oriented representation** of an HTML document, that acts as an **interface** between JavaScript and the document itself and **allows** the creation of **dynamic** web pages.

Source: [w3schools - HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**D** ocument

**O** bject

**M** odel

This is the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).  Either an XML, or HTML, or similar document.  All of those terms mean to parse the document and/or make changes to it (usually by using some available tools like JavaScript or C#).

The best example of a DOM when people use those terms is the HTML document in a browser.  You might want to manipulate the DOM in this case to add something to the web page.