# How can I manipulate the DOM without a library like jQuery?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am used to using jQuery for manipulating the DOM, for example:

```
var mything = $("#mything");
mything.on("click", function() {
    mything.addClass("red");
    mything.html("I have sinned.");
});
```

But now I want to do the same things with Vanilla JavaScript. Is this possible? How can I do it?

> **Notice**: This question is intended to be a comprehensive resource on Vanilla JavaScript DOM manipulation.

Comment: Do you have some questions in mind that would be closed as duplicate of this?

Comment: @Bergi Anything related to basic DOM manipulation. Like "How can I change the text somewhere when something is clicked?" or "Why doesn't document.getElementsByClassName().forEach work?" or similar.

Comment: Uh, but that really is too broad for a single question. I thought you were targeting "*How to write this jQuery code with vanilla JS*" or so only. Can you link specific already-asked questions that I might close?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do people mean when they say "DOM Manipulation"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934826/what-do-people-mean-when-they-say-dom-manipulation)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy No, that's *barely tangentially related*.

Comment: @bjb568: you're asking how to manipulate the DOM. That question answers your "canonical" question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy "What is the DOM" ≠ "How can I manipulate it with Vanilla JS"

Comment: → [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290054/1048572) discussing this question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When manipulating the Document Object Model with Vanilla JS, you will be directly be accessing the [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)s. A document contains [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s, particularly [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)s and [`SVGElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement)s which are both `Node`s. An `Element` may contain [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) too.

## Finding Elements

You can get the first element which matches a CSS selector with [`mynode.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and *all* elements that match the selector with [`myNode.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). Most of the time `myNode` will be `Document`, so you can get anything in the document which matches the selector – however, you can look through only a node's **descendants** when `myNode` is a an element.

```
document.querySelectorAll('p:hover'); // Returns a NodeList of hovered paragraphs
```

This is similar to `jQuery('p:hover')`.

There are also more specialized methods like:

- [`myNode.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`myNode.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
- [`myNode.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [`myNode.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Which have self-explanatory names. Notice that `.getElementBy...` returns a single element while `.getElementsBy...` (plural element**s**) returns a `NodeList`, which is essentially an array of nodes, but it doesn't have the standard array methods.

See also: [What's the best way to loop through a set of elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157260/whats-the-best-way-to-loop-through-a-set-of-elements-in-javascript)

Each element may also have a:

- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)
- [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)
- [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) (excludes text nodes)
- [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)
- [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) (excludes text nodes)
- [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)
- [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) (excludes text nodes)
- [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild)
- [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild) (excludes text nodes)
- [`childElementCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/childElementCount) (same as `children.length`)

And `NodeList`s of:

- [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) (excludes text nodes)

In this way, we can traverse the DOM.

For example, to get the last child of the first paragraph element in the parent of `#clickme` here:

```js
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].lastChild);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <blockquote>This is a really great quote.</blockquote>
  <p>This is a <em>really</em> interesting paragraph. <span>this will be selected</span></p>
  <p>In fact, here's another!</p>
  <button id="clickme">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

...you find its `parentNode`, use `getElementsByTagName` on that to only get paragraph descendants, take the first one of those, and get its `lastChild`.

To get the text contained in it, you could get its text node (its first child) then use `text.wholeText`.

## Creating & Deleting

You can create an element with `document.createElement('aTagName')` or clone another one with `newElement = myElement.cloneNode()`. Pass [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) `true` as it's first argument to also duplicate its descendants. Don't clone elements with an ID because it will cause 2 elements with the same ID to appear in the same document.

You can then append the new element (or an existing one) to a parent element using [`parent.appendChild(newElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or append it after another element with [`parent.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). An `insertAfter` method doesn't exist, but it can be created:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.insertAfter = function(newEl, refEl) {
  if (refEl.nextSibling) refEl.parentNode.insertBefore(newEl, refEl.nextSibling);
  else refEl.parentNode.appendChild(newEl);
};
```

A node can be removed with [`parent.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) or  replaced with [`parent.replaceChild(newChild)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) or just removed inline with [`mynode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).

```js
function poof() {
  this.remove();
}
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('poof');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', poof);
}
```

```html
<span class="poof">hi,</span>
<span class="poof">click</span>
<span class="poof">to</span>
<span class="poof">delete</span>
<span class="poof">me;</span>
<span class="poof">it</span>
<span class="poof">was</span>
<span class="poof">fun</span>
<span class="poof">being</span>
<span class="poof">a</span>
<span class="poof">span</span>
```

## Classes and styles

By "and styles," I mean just classes. **Styles are for CSS.** You can apply CSS styles only to elements who have had a class added with JavaScript.<sup>1</sup>

Elements in HTML have a [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property which is a [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) representing a space-separated property, in this case `class`. You can `.add()`, `.remove()`, and `.toggle()` classes in the classList or check if it `.contains()` a class.

```js
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('colors').classList.toggle('green');
});
```

```css
.green { color: green }
```

```html
<div id="colors">hello!</div>
<button id="clickme">Click me!</button>
```

## Attributes

Elements with certain attributes can be selected with `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. Most attributes are properties of the element you're working with already. For example:

```
myDiv.hidden = true; // Hides element from view and from screenreaders
```

But if they're not, any attribute can be accessed with [`getAttributeNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNode), [`setAttributeNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNode), and [`removeAttributeNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttributeNode). AttributeNodes have *ownerElements* and *value*s.

"data-*" attributes can be accessed with `myelement.dataset`. For example, `mydiv.dataset.pie = 'yummy'` would add `data-pie="yummy"` to the div.

## Events

Events are slightly more complicated. *Binding* one (like `jQuery('selector').on`) is pretty easy:

```
myElement.addEventListener('event-name', afunction);
```

(Other objects also have this method – for example, `window`)

Events can also be removed:

```
myelement.removeEventListener('event-name', afunction);
```

See: [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

An event list can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

The function passed to the `addEventListener` will be passed an argument of the event occurring and have a `this` of the element the event listener is *bound* to.

However, events aren't this simple: something as trivial as clicking on a button may fire many event listeners on different elements and for different events.

[image: Click event path on iOS]

– [Browser Input Events: Can We Do Better Than The Click?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/03/20/better-browser-input-events/) by Smashing Magazine

See also: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you really need to modify a style with JS, use `myElement.style.styleProperty = 'value'` to change the *inline style attribute*.</sub>

Comment: This would be a lot easier to take in for someone new to this if there were clearly listed (close to) equivalents for common jQuery methods.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I edited in 2, but I'm not well-versed in jQuery. You can add more jQuery equivalents yourself (community-wiki answer).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy [YouMightNotNeedjQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) is around for a while, you could reference it for more info.