# How to do this jQuery code into Javascript without depending on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have some dependencies issue where jQuery i cant use but at the same time i need to make this work, any idea how you can do this without jQuery libraries.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function after2SecPreset1() {
    $('#sptouchscreen').hide();       
    return ;
  }

  function before2SecPreset1() {  
    console.log('before2secpreset1');
  }  

  var clickstart;
  var clickstop;
  $('#sptouchscreen').on('mousedown', function(e) {    
      clickstart = e.timeStamp;
  }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
      clickstop = e.timeStamp- clickstart;
      if(clickstop >= 2000) {
        after2SecPreset1();
      } else { 
        before2SecPreset1();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Plain JavaScript? :-b

Comment: YES - how to do the on.mousedown and  on.mouseup ?

Comment: You need to go step -by-step. Here is the [tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29596358/4454454)

Comment: Just teasing... `document.getElementById('element').addEventListener('mousedown', ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `$(document).ready`, add an event listener to `document` for the event `"DOMContentLoaded"`.

For `.hide()`, set the `style.display` property of the element to `"none"`.

For `.on()`, use `.addEventListener` instead.

Comment: First one `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });`