# Change main content on a webpage using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a webpage using `Bootstrap 3`. I am trying to find the best way to change the main content of the side.  I have a Header, left content and right content but I want to change the middle content by pushing a button without changing the surrounding elements. What would be the best thing to use to accomplish this. Is there some demos online that someone can point out?  I have been trying to find some but without luck.

Comment: you could use javascript , ajax, html iframe......

Comment: Why Bootstrap? Because it's so popular??

Comment: Why Bootstrap - Well I am just making a side that need to be responsive and Bootstrap seems at the beginning at least  to be a good solution. Would you recommend some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't have that feature. First try to learn what bootstrap can do or can't, what bootstrap made for.

What you are trying to do is called templating. You can use php, ajax or other methods to dynamically add content to your content section of your template.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do that, maybe with [jQuery `.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) and maybe combined with [**HTML5 history API**](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) or some other framework...

But Bootstrap has nothing to do with that..

You can start reading about [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and [DOM manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934826/what-do-people-mean-by-dom-manipulation-and-how-would-i-do-that) first, but here is some link you can use:

> [Dynamically Loading Content in Twitter Bootstrap Tabs](http://blog.chewxy.com/2011/10/30/dynamically-loading-content-in-twitter-bootstrap-tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with boot strap that is just not what it's made for you can use either PHP or Ajax personally if you know PHP already and have everything set up for go with that because in my opinion Ajax sucks to learn and work with