# cleaning up angularjs controller and function - for drop down list with multi select custom made

Tags: html, angularjs, performance

how can I clean up this code.  here is my function in my controller.  I am using this to  control 3 different custom made drop down lists in my html.  I want when you click out of them, they close.  I wish I didn't need to give them each their own variable for ng-show, but I think I do because if ng-show is true for one then they would all show together.  Also is it wrong to put all this in a controller rather than a directive or factory or something - besides for cleaning up the function itself.

```
 $scope.toggle = function (option,type) {   
                if (option == 'subdiv') {
                        $scope.notMain = true;
                        if ($scope.notMain) {
                                if (type == 'item') {
                                    $scope.showItemOptions = true;
                                    $scope.showOptions = false;
                                    $scope.showOrderOptions = false;
                                }
                            else if (type == 'style') {
                                $scope.showOptions = true;
                                $scope.showItemOptions = false;
                                $scope.showOrderOptions = false;
                            }
                            else if (type == 'order') {
                                $scope.showOrderOptions = true;
                                $scope.showItemOptions = false;
                                $scope.showOptions = false;
                            }
                        }
                }//end of if subdiv
                else if (option == 'maindiv') {
                    if (!$scope.notMain) {                        
                            $scope.showItemOptions = false;                
                            $scope.showOptions = false;
                            $scope.showOrderOptions = false;
                    }
                    $scope.notMain = false;
                }//end of if maindiv
            };
```

here is the html for just one of the drop downs (but they are all the same with different variables:

```
 <div class="dropdownlistheader"   ng-click="toggle('subdiv','order')">
 <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="dropdownlistinput" value="{{selectedOrderValuesDisplay}}" /> </div>
 <div id="ddl123" ng-show="showOrderOptions" class="dropdownlist">
  <div ng-show="showOrderOptions" ng-repeat="option in OrdersDDL">
<label> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-click="toggleOrderSelection(option.Number, option.Details)">  {{option.Details}}</label> </div></div>
```

Comment: would appreciate any advice even if someone can clean up any part of the code

Comment: The controller should definitely be 'skinnier' than this. Too many scope variables [slows the digest cycle](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135), decreasing performance. Does your code work as is? Could you put it in a plunkr/fiddle/codepen. I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I will try to add to plunker.  but how do you avoid scope variables.

Comment: There are a number of ways. At a bare minimum, you should be using `var` for anything that you're not binding to the view. It's tough to say without knowing exactly what you're doing. But in general, for DOM manipulation, you would use directives, and for complex business logic, you would use a service/factory. [This link](http://demisx.github.io/angularjs/2014/09/14/angular-what-goes-where.html) has a useful table showing what generally goes where in Angular. [This link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers) shows an example of making a controller 'skinnier'.

Comment: does  DOM manimulation include custom made drop downs  and the code that causes them to open and close?

Comment: In a nutshell yes. Simplistically, you could think of it as relating to the page visuals - what you see and interact with. So when you click the dropdown, you might want it to be highlighted or animated, in which case you need to change the DOM. However, the data/logic used in determining what to populate the dropdown with, is not DOM manipulation. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934826/what-do-people-mean-by-dom-manipulation-and-how-would-i-do-that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the whole thing to one function.  was able to do it easily by changing the ng-show variables to contain the text of of the name of the ddl that should show instead of bool like they were.

```
  $scope.toggle = function (option,type) {
        if (option == 'subdiv') {
                $scope.notMain = true;
                if ($scope.notMain) {
                    $scope.showDDL = type;
                }
        }
        else if (option == 'maindiv') {
            if (!$scope.notMain) {
                $scope.showDDL = '';
            }
            $scope.notMain = false;
        }
    };
```

in html:  ng-show=="type" //type is hardcoded in html